# Is there any to Open java enabled wabpage without enabling webView in Android

Tags: java, android, webview

This is my WebView Code

```
 private fun setupWebView() {
    webViewFromActivity.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.WV_URL))
    webViewFromActivity.webViewClient = mWebViewClient
    //webViewFromActivity.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webViewFromActivity.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webViewFromActivity.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
}
```

if i enable javascript then a error arise Vulnerable classes--

> Your app includes a WebView that is vulnerable to cross app scripting. Please see this Google Help >Center article for details.
>
> Vulnerable classes:
>
> com.all.in.one.shopping.app.india.activity.WebViewActivity->setupWebView

So i need alternative of enableJavaScript otherwise javaScript url is not openning